# For a DataFrame with sorted, numeric index and columns return the tuple of index values and column names closest to the given values passed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am working with a DataFrame having sorted numeric index and columns:

```
    6    9    15    22
3   5    2     1     7
5   0    2     9     1
8   7    3     1     1
```

Given some values of index and column name, for example (6, 12), I would like to obtain the slice of the original DataFrame:

```
    9    15
5   2     9
8   3     1
```

Or the index values, so for the same example of (6, 12), the result would be:

```
(5, 9), (8, 15)
```

In case the input is matching the index or column names, then the return slice should be adjusted, for example for (8, 12) the return slice should be:

```
    9    15
8   3     1
```

Which could be interpreted in the index result as:

```
(8, 9), (8, 15)
```

And in the best case of matching index and column names, for example (8, 9) it should be:

```
    9
8   3
```

Which could be interpreted in the index (to be consistent) result as:

```
(8, 9), (8, 9)
```

Comment: What is the rule of slicing here? I understand input is (index, column) -> in our example (6, 12), but what does it mean? It should be taken indexes and columns larger than or ...?

Comment: What happen if `(6, 15)` ? Or `(8, 12)` ?

Comment: The rule is to obtain the closest pair of index and column names to the given values provided. Thank you for the good point, I have updated the description to reduce the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bit modified [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36275584):

```
def get_closest_pair(i,c,t):
    return [(i[i <= t[0]].max(),c[c <= t[1]].max()),
            (i[i >= t[0]].min(),c[c >= t[1]].min())]

print (get_closest_pair(df.index, df.columns, (6,12)))
[(5, 9), (8, 15)]

print (get_closest_pair(df.index, df.columns, (8,12)))
[(8, 9), (8, 15)]

print (get_closest_pair(df.index, df.columns, (8,9)))
[(8, 9), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: It turns out that my column names are read as int already, so no need to `c = c.str.strip("'").astype(int)`, that was my mistake. Works great!