# Finding the second closest number above and below in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I have pulled the row closest to `t_ave` that is calculated early in my code. I now want to present the user with the next closest options above and below the best choice.

```
df_sc = pd.DataFrame()

df_sc['Diff'] = df_sc.Average.apply(lambda z: t_ave-z)
df_sc['Abs_Diff'] = df_sc.Diff.apply(lambda z: abs(z))
df_sc = df_sc.sort_values(by=['Abs_Diff'])

print('The best option is:', df_sc.iloc[0]['Name'])
```

Here is an example of my dataframe after I have done the above sorting:

```
   Name   Average   Diff     Abs_Diff
2   C5    -11.0     -1.0       1.0
3   C6    -7.5      -4.5       4.5
4   C7    -5.0      -7.0       7.0
1   C4    -22.0     10.0      10.0
0   C3    -26.0     12.0      12.0
5   C8     0.0     -12.0      12.0
6  C10     5.0     -17.0      17.0
```

This works well to find the best option (here it is `C5`) but I am having difficulty finding the next best options. I was initially trying to use the `.drop` method to drop my top result and then find the next closest. But, while this helps to find the next closest it does not tell me which direction it is relative to the top option `Average` and so I cannot then determine the next closest in the opposite direction.

In the current sorting say `t_ave` is -15, the best option is `C5`, the closest larger option is `C6` with an `Average` value of -7.5. The closest smaller option is `C4` with an `Average` value of -22.

There are questions similar to this like this one: [Find the closest elements above and below a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275459/find-the-closest-elements-above-and-below-a-given-number), but this question is based off of a user input number and not a value in a dataframe.

Comment: When you say "next best option", what's wrong with, e.g. `df_sc.iloc[1]['Name']` for the second best?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Those answer don't depend on the value coming from *user input*; they're parameterized for a value from any source.

Comment: `df.Abs_Diff.nsmallest(2).iloc[-1]` ..??

Comment: Or instead of picking the name, pick the index (which would be 2 for C5), and then increment and decrement that.

Comment: In the remainder of the list, you need the first positive and the first negative value.  One of them is at `iloc[1]`.

Comment: @Lagerbaer and @Prune `.iloc[1]` would work to find the next closest but doesn't help me determine which direction it is relative to the top option. I am wanting determine the next two closest options, one greater than and one less than my current selection. If I hard code the index, this will give me the incorrect answer as the next time the code is run the rows are re-sorted as shown in the first code block

Comment: @anky_91 `.nsmallest(2).iloc[-1]` does not work in this case as it will give me the next two closest and not necessarily the next greater than and the next less than values. In my current sorting, the next two closest values sorted by absolute difference are both greater than my top selection. I had not seen `.nsmallest` before so thank you for showing me something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the DataFrame based on the `Average` column and then return the results as you have done above.

```
best_average = df_sc.iloc[0]['Average']

name_of_one_bigger = df_sc[df_sc.Average > best_Average].iloc[0]['Name']
name_of_one_smaller = df_sc[df_sc.Average < best_Average].iloc[0]['Name']
```