# Find the closest boundries value pair that an integer can reside with Numpy or Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance

Given a 1D `array`

```
a=np.array([ 65, 251, 431])
```

and another 1D `array` used to construct the boundaries.

```
b=np.array([  4,  10,  18,  22,  28,  33,  40,  49,  72,  83,  90,  93,  99,
              107, 113, 119, 130, 142, 161, 167, 173, 178, 183, 196, 202, 209,
              215, 221, 228, 233, 240, 258, 262, 269, 274, 281, 286, 297, 311,
              317, 352, 354, 358, 365, 371, 376, 382, 389, 396, 413, 420, 441,
              443, 450, 459, 467, 473, 477, 483, 491, 495, 497])
```

For example, the two point boundries can be of coordinate `4,10` , `4,18`, `4,497`,...,`495,497`.

The objective is to find the closest boundary  value pair that an integer (e.g., every integer in array a) can reside.

For example the value `65`, the closest boundary that it can reside is `49,72`.

The code below should answer the objective

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a=np.array([ 65, 251, 431])

# Assumed `b` is sorted from lowest to highest value and no duplicate values
b=np.array([  4,  10,  18,  22,  28,  33,  40,  49,  72,  83,  90,  93,  99,
              107, 113, 119, 130, 142, 161, 167, 173, 178, 183, 196, 202, 209,
              215, 221, 228, 233, 240, 258, 262, 269, 274, 281, 286, 297, 311,
              317, 352, 354, 358, 365, 371, 376, 382, 389, 396, 413, 420, 441,
              443, 450, 459, 467, 473, 477, 483, 491, 495, 497])


leadB =b[:-1]
trailB=b[1:]

all_val=[]
for dis_a in a:
    for l,t in zip(leadB,trailB):
        if l < dis_a <= t:
            all_val.append({'a':dis_a,'lb':l,'tb':t})

# The final output can be in the form of pandas or numpy array
df=pd.DataFrame(all_val)
```

But, the above approach rely heavily on the two stage `for-loop`. I wonder wheter there is efficient way of doing this either with build-in function of `Numpy` or `Pandas`.

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275459/find-the-closest-elements-above-and-below-a-given-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be ideal problem for using `np.searchsorted`, however there can be two possible solutions depending upon your actual requirements:

- If all the elements in `a` are guaranteed to fall between the boundary points:

```py
i = np.searchsorted(b, a)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'lb': b[i - 1], 'tb': b[i]})
```

- If some elements of `a` do not fall in boundary points then a more general solution would be:

```py
i = np.searchsorted(b, a)
m = ~np.isin(i, [0, len(b)])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a})
df.loc[m, 'lb'], df.loc[m, 'tb'] = b[i[m] - 1], b[i[m]]
```

Result

```
     a   lb   tb
0   65   49   72
1  251  240  258
2  431  420  441
```

Comment: Really appreciate for the `general solution`. I have not consider this before.